# Combine two array matching key in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I need to Combine two array in PHP，and also have to match the keys

Here`s my array

array1 look like

```
[
    0 => "num",
    1 => "No",
    2 => "Name",
    3 => "Phone",
    4 => "Price",
    5 => "Date"
]
```

array2 look like

```
[
    0 =>[
        "No" => "FR201605832",
        "Price" => 199.0,
        "Date" => "2016-09-01",
        "num" => "19",
        "Name" => "Tom",
        "Phone" => "0900123456"
    ],
    1 =>[
        "No" => "EC2016010100001",
        "Price" => 1680.0,
        "Date" => "2016-09-01",
        "num" => "1680",
        "Name" => "Ted",
        "Phone" => "0900321654"
    ]
]
```

And Here`s Result What I want

```
[
    0 =>[
        "num" => "19",
        "No" => "FR201605832",
        "Name" => "Tom",
        "Phone" => "0900123456",
        "Price" => 199.0,
        "Date" => "2016-09-01",
    ],
    1 => [
        "num" => "1680",
        "No" => "EC2016010100001",
        "Name" => "Ted",
        "Phone" => "0900321654",
        "Price" => 1680.0,
        "Date" => "2016-09-01",
    ]
]
```

array1 is User reOrder the input excel heading，I can get the reorder request but don`t know how to combine with the value

Plz help me to combine two array and export the expect result，Thx

---

Here is the next step

Renam the Result array key by array3

array3 look like

> array:6 [▼
>
> "num" => "id"
>
> "No" => "ECNo"
>
> "Name" => "User"
>
> "Phone" => "Mobile"
>
> "Price" => "Total"
>
> "Date" => "PayDay"
>
> ]

I tried

> foreach($exportdata as &$val){
>
> $val[$values] = $val[$keys];
>
> unset($val[$value]);
>
> }

But get error Illegal offset type

any good idea?

Comment: you need to sort (order) second array by first array ??

Comment: @Hamelraj Yes,Just like you said...

Comment: now check my answer i have include another way Ryan

Comment: @Hamelraj Can u help me check out any other way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [array_flip()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) and [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to achieve your result

```
$new = [];
foreach ($array as $value) {
  $new[] = array_merge(array_flip($order),$value);
}
dd($new);
```

you can order your second array when you create that array. without go for another foreach 
so your second array data something different i guess so try this way

```
$new = [];
foreach ($array as $value) {
   if(isset($value['num'])) $data['num'] = $value['num'];
   if(isset($value['No'])) $data['No'] = $value['No'];
   if(isset($value['Name'])) $data['Name'] = $value['Name'];
   if(isset($value['Phone'])) $data['Phone'] = $value['Phone'];
   if(isset($value['Price'])) $data['Price'] = $value['Price'];
   if(isset($value['Date'])) $data['Date'] = $value['Date'];

   $new[] = $data;
}
```

Comment: do directly `$new[] = array_merge(array_flip($order),$value);`. No need of extra variable `$route_list`.It will make answer more effective

Comment: @AlivetoDie Thank u too ~

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
$modified = [];
foreach($parent as $i => $val) {
    foreach($child as $ci => $data) {
        $modified[$ci][$val] = $data[$val];
    }
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($modified);
```

Output:-https://3v4l.org/amNep